# Multithreading with cursors in Google Datastore

Tags: multithreading, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, cursors

I want to load a lot of data from Google Datastore.

So, Step 1: I run the query (using keysOnly=true) and loop through the cursors, so that each one is pointing to the start of a page of 600 objects. I store the cursors in a local variable.

Step 2: I spin off one thread per cursor, loading and processing 600 objects in each thread.

It is not the usual way that cursors are used.

However, it looks correct to me. The actual query strings in Step 1 and Step 2 are identical. This resembles the usual stateless web use-case where a user may ask for Next, Back, then reload a previous page; there is no need for a cursor to come directly from the result of the previous cursor-query.

I don't want to step through cursors sequentially and then spin off threads in order to parallelize the processing of objects loaded in a given cursor-query, because I want to parallelize the actual IO-intensive querying from the DB.

I am getting some inconsistency in results that seem to involve missed pages and duplicate loading of objects. Is this the correct way to multithread the loading of large amounts of data from Google Datastore? Or if not, what is?

Comment: did you solve that? I have a simliar problem.

Comment: LocationsCloudToHub One approach is to load each entity from Darattiore sequentially, but then spin off the initialisation process for each one in a new thread, or use a queue. See @Andrei Volgin answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ed Davisson, a Google engineer who works on the Google Datastore Client API, [answered this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gcd-discuss/BGecRthhJ1w/uz6hpeUBCwAJ). He provided the root cause of the problem and a recommended solution.

He says:

"The cursors returned by a query are only valid for use in the same query. When you switch from the keys-only query [In my Step 1, JF] to the non-keys-only query [In my Step 2, JF], the cursors are no longer applicable....

"If your goal is to split a result set into similar sized chunks, you might want to take a look at [QuerySplitter](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/blob/master/java/datastore/src/main/java/com/google/datastore/v1beta3/client/QuerySplitter.java) [which is now in version 1beta3, JF]."

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend a different approach. Run only one query that cycles through all of your entities. It happens very fast (don't forget to set the batch size to 500, the default is only 10). You still may need to use cursors, if the query is huge.

For every entity create a task using Task API and add it to the task queue. These tasks can be executed in parallel. You can set all the parameters on your queue.

With this approach you don't have to worry about threads, you can set tasks to automatically retry when they fail, etc. I find it to be a very important part of the App Engine's appeal - write only your own logic, and let App Engine worry about the execution part.

Comment: Thank you, that could work. But the slow part is the actual queries, rather than  per-entity post-processing. You said that it happens fast, but the bottleneck is IO.

Comment: You only need a key to create a task, and then `get` an entity within a task. Use a keys-only query, and it will be much faster.

Comment: Thank you. Are you saying that I should iterate sequentially through all objects (using cursors if necessary) with a keys-only  query? Then subsequently, do the get operations in parallel (using tasks)? That does mean hitting the DB twice for each entity, right?

Comment: 1. Yes, this is what I recommend. 2. Keys and indexed properties are stored in indexes. Entities are stored separately. A keys-only query only reads from the indexes. A regular query does the same, and *then* retrieves and returns entities. By moving `get` to the task you can retrieve many entities in parallel (as tasks are executed in parallel), without the constraints of your query loop.

Comment: Also, a task has to be stored (it's done by the App Engine automatically). If you retrieve an entity in a query and then store it in a task, you effectively read an entity twice and store it once. But if you only store a key, you only read the entity once. This improves overall performance by a lot.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like the right direction . But you are proposing doing one get query per entity. Isn't it better to do a cursor query to get the full object contents and so to load 500 complete objects in one query? This would greatly reduce the number of queries and so save IO.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're doing, you have a few options:

1. If you have a large amount of data - use a 'fan out' model with task queues. In this model, task queue jobs load a segment of data, process it and store a result, and possibly trigger more processing jobs. Taskqueue throttling allows you to control throughput/duration/cost and also handle failure/retry. An advantage of this model is you can test and rerun segments by poking URLs manually, and view progress in the admin panel.
2. Use GAE MapReduce - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/dataprocessing/
3. In a single process if you have a small amount of data. The drawback is request deadline (60s, 10m or 24hrs - depending on the type of server and request). Recall that datastore operations are asynchronous, so you can run requests in parallel in a single thread, which may simplify your code. How many before they become blocking is (I believe) controlled by `max-concurrent-requests` in your appengine-web.xml or app.yaml. This can be very expensive if your request can fail and isn't built to be resumable.

Comment: Thank you. I am simply loading a lot of objects into  memory, with minimal postprocessing on each. There are a number of options fer parallelizing the load, but the real question is: How do I do Cursors? I tried iterate over all objects to gather Cursor strings (which demarcate "pages" of, say, 1000 objects), and then distribute the Cursors across threads,  loading one Cursor's-worth of objects per thread (or I could use Tasks, MapReduce, asynchronous DB calls, etc). But that  design requires two iterations, and in any case causes strange inconsistencies in the results.

Comment: You haven't told us what you want to do with the data, so it's challenging to give you specific help. If you are trying to get a full snapshot of the datastore using eventually consistent queries (cursors or otherwise), you will get symptoms  such as 'missed' or duplicate objects, unless your data is very static. Cursors work in the general sense (although not necessarily on the dev server)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to load into memory a full snapshot of a given table with eventually consistent queries. There are thousands  of objects, so I am using cursors of 800 objects at a time. Why should that cause missed or duplicate objects? I know that if an object is added or deleted after cursors are gathered, I might not see that, but shouldn't everything else be OK? My DB actually is static while this happens: I even experienced missing and duplicate objects in Read-Only mode with this approach (gathering cursors and loading a page's worth of objects per thread).